# how to change MFA Phone Number within updateProfile Page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

i can successfully Change MFA Phone Number using Edit MFA Number sample [Edit MFA Phone Number](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/edit-mfa-phone-number)

and separately I can call "SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate" in user journey to update the profile (givenname and surname).

i want to have one single profile edit page with pre filled givenname, surname and MFA Phone number, and user can edit them and update them.
so question is, is it possible to have MFA Phone number editable in the same page where givenname and surname are edited.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible and here are the steps:

For updating the profile attributes first, you need to add `extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail` as an [output claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#output-claims) in your profile (edit technical profile). The starter uses the technical profile called SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate. ([link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L909))

Then save the attribute to the dictionary by adding `extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail` as persisted claim to technical profile AAD`UserWriteProfileUsingObjectid`. ([link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L796))

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile) about the Azure Active Directory technical profile in Azure Active Directory B2C custom policy.

Comment: ok but by doing this how can i add MFA Phone number field in edit profile page to edit, and how can i edit MFA Number on same page with other attributes, how this solution answers my asked question, please elaborate more in detail, thanks

Comment: You can simply add this MFA phone input field in your edit profile page like you added surname and givenname input field. Remember to add output claims as mentioned above. Then save these attributes to the directory by adding extension_mfaByPhoneOrEmail as persisted claim to profile. These steps are similar to when you updated something like username etc. You would then need to send the claims to the directory. Follow this document for a complete guidance.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile